# Where does the Samba workgroup come from when Samba is not running?

Tags: networking, command-line, samba

Using [`findsmb`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/findsmb.1.html) on my home network gives me this:

```
IP ADDR         NETBIOS NAME     WORKGROUP/OS/VERSION 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.1.3     MINI           [MSHOME] [Unix] [Samba 3.0.25b-apple]
192.168.1.9     SERVER        +[    MSHOME        ]
192.168.1.11    NAS            [    WORKGROUP     ]
```

- MINI - a Mac mini
- SERVER - Ubuntu 10.10 server; Samba installed but not running.
- NAS - another Ubuntu 10.10 server; Samba installed but not running.

When Samba is running the Ubuntu groups are the values from `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, but with Samba turned off it falls back to these defaults - even different defaults for two installations of the same OS.

I would like to change the workgroups, but I can't figure out where the value is coming from: Not from Samba (that's a different value), not from Winbind (not running), not from Avahi (not installed); and I don't know of anything else involved in network groups.

How can I find this setting so I can change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your workground name comes from the `NetBIOS Name server` which is running on your Ubuntu machines. It's shipped with Samba.

You can change the workgroup name in samba configuration `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and then restart the NetBIOS server using init:

```
sudo service nmbd restart
```

You can also remove this service from running, but check the Samba documentation about what it does and if you need it:

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/nmbd.8.html

Comment: I know, I turned it on in OS X to share files between Mac and Ubuntu. Turning it off makes the OS X share disappear from the findsmb listing, as expected.

Comment: OK, found which Ubuntu service the workgroup name is coming from: `nmbd` - stopping nmbd makes the computer disappear from the list, and restarting it gave me the workgroup name I expected. I think the issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks j-g-faustus, I've updated my answer so the next person who searches and finds this question will know what to do.